# Ubuntu on external Seagate haddrive works on Desktop but not on laptop

Tags: boot, laptop

I just installed Ubuntu onto my Seagate 1tb external HDD.  It works and boots perfectly fine on my desktop.  However, on my laptop it seems like it boots up, it loads in and then opens what looks like a terminal writes a few lines, stalls for a minute and then the Laptop shuts off.  The laptop and Desktop are both running Windows 10.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: What release of Ubuntu?  Was it Ubuntu Desktop? or Ubuntu Server?  How did you install it? (normal install? live with persistence?)  Did you check nothing machine specific was in the file system table?  Are both machines same architecture? Assuming desktop, could you boot to runlevel 1? or what were the last messages you saw? (ie. `quiet splash` removed)  The few lines could be nothing but `fsck` because of last shutdown; were they?  Some details may help us understand what you have.

Comment: Sorry I was so vague haha, it is 18.04.03 Desktop.  I believe live.  I used a USB flash and went into the trial of Ubuntu and installed it from there onto my external drive.  I'll submit a picture of what it says right now.  I get to choose normal Ubuntu then it runs the lines (I will send a picture of) then it goes to the Ubuntu loading screen and then crashes. @guiverc

Comment: https://m.imgur.com/a/fpG6TfA

Comment: The few lines are a `fsck` (file system check) because of the unclean shutdown the time before (as I suggested; result 'clean') and mean nothing (except you didn't shutdown properly last time, or it was the 30th boot & thus time to `fsck` anyway).  Did you edit grub, remove the 'quiet splash' from the linux [kernel] line so you can see messages instead of `plymouth` graphics (that hides messages that may provide clues; hitting ESC may achieve this when plymouth graphic is on display too; https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters).   Please add additional detail to your question.